# how a python single-thread server can handle multi-client

Tags: python, client-server, django-views

I have a server in python that provides pages. The log-in to these pages is done using an IdP (identity provider). So when the user tries to open my server page, he is redirected to the IdP page. In the meanwhile my server starts listening for the IdP response. When the user logs in the in IdP page, the IdP sends data to my server, that handles them and shows my page to the user.

The problem is that if multiple clients try to log in, when the server receives the first response from one IdP, all the users will show my page as logged in with the credential of the first user.

I mean, when the server starts listening, it's awaiting for everyone. When just the first user logs in, all the user that are awaiting logs with the same credentials.

How can I solve this very big problem? Multithreading may help?

Here some of the important code. Let's say that i want to load some of the data answered by the idp, into the fields 'name' of the login-form of my page.

```
class Login(django.forms.SelfHandlingForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Login, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        response = self.getIdPResponse()
        self.fields['name'].widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'value': response['name']})


    def getIdPResponse(self):
        global response
        response = None
        timeout = 300
        class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
            def do_POST(self):
                global response
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                self.end_headers()
                varLen = int(self.headers["Content-Length"])
                #response = urlparse.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(varLen))
                response = self.rfile.read(varLen)

                self.wfile.write("Log-in ok! now you can close this page.")
        httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), RequestHandler)
        try:
            httpd.socket.settimeout(1)
        except BaseException as e:
            print e
        count = 0
        '''at this point, the IdP page is already showed to the user '''
        while response is None and count < timeout:
           try:
               httpd.handle_request()
               count = count + 1
               print 'waiting for the Idp answer...'
           except Exception as e:
               print e
        return response
```

in this way, when an user successfully logs-in, all the user that are waiting to login, will show in the field 'name' the name of the user that first logged in. Obviously I don't want this.

Comment: Please include some code, specifically the parts that are relevant here, how do you validate the clients, and how are you parsing their credentials?

Comment: ok, I edited my question with the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what Useless knew that I don't when he answered you, but which software provides the server functionality? Is it a Python stand-alone piece of software, or do you have apache/nginx/... set up?

Comment: I have apache...but it doesn't involved in this strictly code snipped. Let's say that I just want to show on my page (built by python), some data answered by the IdP.

Comment: @ClassStacker - I'm just going by the code posted, which is using `BaseHTTPServer` directly

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use an event-driven system, like [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), to split your `getIdPResponse` method into two parts:

1. send the request
2. handle the response

then your single thread doesn't block, and can dispatch events for other clients in the meantime.

If you want to simplify your application logic, you *could* wrap a layer of blocking calls on top of this, but it's not what I'd recommend.

Comment: mm i want that the threas is blocking actually..  because I need to get the answer before to show the page, otherwise I couldn't put data into the charField. If the thread were not-blocking, the page would shows-up before the idp answer.

Comment: Nope, that's not the right way to think about it. Under the event-driven model, you choose when to write data to a given client, so you just choose not to write anything to that client until the data is ready. It just means you can handle _other_ clients' requests while you wait.